# Ошибка в layout если добавить ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout

В общем, простая Activity, в которой добавлен только 1 ListView

```
public class ActivityMessenger extends Activity {

    ListView listChat = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_messenger);
    }

}
```

Файл activity_messenger.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/fon">

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ошибка:

```
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cj.serverconnect/com.cj.serverconnect.ActivityMessenger}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1896)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at com.cj.serverconnect.ActivityMessenger.onCreate(ActivityMessenger.java:15)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5119)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    ... 11 more
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    ... 24 more
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010051 a=2}
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1927)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:772)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:143)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:139)
10-15 10:45:47.993: E/AndroidRuntime(19897):    ... 27 more
```

Если в место ListView поставить скажем Button то ошибок не будет.

Файл styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/itemTextStyle.AppTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/menuFon</item> 
</style>

<style name="Theme.stylingactionbar.widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="itemTextStyle.AppTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Файл AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.cj.serverconnect"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityMessenger"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_messenger" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что выбранная тема для Activity, или же целого приложения имеет ошибки стиля для `ListView`. Покажите манифест, и, если используете свои собственные стили - покажите и их

Comment: Добавил стиль и манифест

Comment: Попробуйте запустить без этой строчки `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. Если запустится, значит проблема точно в теме. Я ничего криминального в стилях не вижу, но проверьте еще на всякий случай, что цвета вроде `@color/menuFon` имеют правильные значения

Comment: Ошибка в теме, да, запустилась без использования темы, как найти ошибку?

Comment: Изменил стиль на <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">, работает, но меню сверху исчезло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно разобрался, благодаря [metalurgus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3997/metalurgus). 
Изменил стиль

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/itemTextStyle.AppTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/menuFon</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.stylingactionbar.widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="itemTextStyle.AppTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```